# C++ How would the calling of these functions change if i change the parameter argument from an int* to int

Tags: c++

First of all, i have no idea how to word the title whilst keeping it descriptive if anybody has a better idea feel free to edit.

My question is as follows; I have been given a set of function definitions and calls to these functions which currently operate using an int* as the variable that is being passed in various ways to these functions.

My task is to without changing the function definitions make the program compile and produce the same output but this time use an int over an int*.

Desired output:

```
Result
first 43
second 43
third 44
fourth 0
fifth 69
```

This is the code for the when the variable is an int*

```
void MyIncrementFirst(int* i) {
(*i)++;
}

void MyIncrementSecond(int i) {
i++;
}

void MyIncrementThird(int & i) {
i++;
}

void MyIncrementFourth(int** i) {
*i = new int(0);
}

void MyIncrementFifth(int*& i) {
i = new int(69);
}


int main(){

int* a = new int(42);
cout << "Result" << endl;

MyIncrementFirst(a);
cout << "first " <<*a << endl;

MyIncrementSecond(*a);
cout << "second " <<*a << endl;

MyIncrementThird(*a);
cout << "third " <<*a << endl;


MyIncrementFourth(&a);
cout << "fourth " <<*a << endl;

MyIncrementFifth(a);
cout << "fifth " <<*a << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Now here is what i have so far when changing the type of a to an int, not an int*:

Note: The function definitions are the same as above.

int main(){

```
int a = 42;
cout << "Result" << endl;

MyIncrementFirst(&a);
cout << "first " <<a << endl;

MyIncrementSecond(a);
cout << "second " <<a << endl;

MyIncrementThird(a);
cout << "third " <<a << endl;

/*
MyIncrementFourth(&a);
cout << "fourth " <<a << endl;

MyIncrementFifth(a);
cout << "fifth " <<a << endl;
*/
return 0;

}
```

Which prints:

```
Result
first 43
second 43
third 44
```

Calls to MyIncrementFourth and MyIncrementFith have been commented because i am not sure how to translate this to handle an int rather than an int*. Any attempts i do would just be fluke rather than knowledge.

Can anybody help me identify how to correctly complete the calls to MyIncrementFourth and MyIncrementFith in order to achieve a correct result.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: "but this time use an int over an int*." where?

Comment: when `a` is used. The second block defines `int a = 42;`. The first block states `int * a = new int(42);`

Comment: Why has this been closed as duplicate? The linked question asks about the case where `a` is a pointer-to-int and this specifically asks about the case where `a` is an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
 int a = 42;
```

instead of

```
 int* a = new int(42);
```

fourth and fifth function can't be used. The `MyIncrementFourth` and `MyIncrementFifth` (counterintuitive names, by the way) pretend to replace the pointer you allocated in the main with another pointer to another area, allocated inside the functions (and there will be a memory leak since you no longer will be able to delete the original `a`…). But if you stick to `int a = 42` instead of `int* a = new int(42)`, your variable is not a pointer, thus those functions have no pointer they can replace.

Comment: The code is not mine, its from an exam paper at school. Thanks for your response, the question states "using the same functions show the changes needed when using a as type int not int*" so maybe they do want you to change the functions.

Comment: if you can change them, then since their effect is nothing but show a different value for `a`, they both become very similar to something already written: in the first you pass the pointer (caller `&a`, callee `int*` as prototype and `*i = 0` as code), in the second you go by reference (caller `a`, callee `int&` as prototype and `i = 69` as code)

Comment: "can't be used"?  I  don't think you are trying hard enough :)

Comment: @ChrisDrew you can for sure find a way to use them, but I doubt it would be worth noting.

Answer (score 2):

```
void foo(int a) {
 ...
}

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  foo(a);
  return 0;
}
```

While with * it would be like this

```
void foo(int* a) {
 ...
}

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  foo(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

However, this reminds of `C`.

You could use the `&` operator, instead of the `*`, like this:

```
void foo(int& a) {
 ...
}

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  foo(a);
  return 0;
}
```

I assume you know what passing by value and by reference means. If you want a refresh, take a look in my example [here](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/functions-in-c/).

[EDIT]

Also note that the code in the first block of yours is not OK, since you call `new` twice, but you never call `delete`.

Also, about what you are asking, you **cannot** do it without using an extra pointer. In other words, it can not be done by only having `int a` in the play.

Example:

```
  int* a_pointer = &a;
  MyIncrementFourth(&a_pointer);
  cout << "fourth " << a << ", but a_pointer points to " << *a_pointer << endl;
```

Why the value of `a` did not change, despite the fact that we set the `a_pointer` to be equal with the address of `a`.

Because inside your function, you are calling `new` and as you know, it will return a pointer to the new allocated memory.

As a result, `a_pointer` is assigned a new value. Which value? The address of the new allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int* ap = &a;
MyIncrementFourth(&ap);
MyIncrementFifth(ap);
// These calls change what ap points to.
// It does not change the value a.
```

You can also use:

```
int* ap = NULL;
MyIncrementFourth(&ap);
MyIncrementFifth(ap);
// These calls change what ap points to.
```

Comment: That does not work. The compiler states: `error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'void MyIncrementFourth(int**)'` You have misread my question. I can get the code working using `a` as type `int*` but not when it is an `int`, thus `&a` means `int*` not `int**`

Comment: The code in the first block works. You are trying to figure out how to make the second code block work. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The code you posted works fine when `int * a = new int(42);` is used, but not when `int a = 42;` is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* ptr;

MyIncrementFourth(&ptr);
a = *ptr;
delete ptr;
std::cout << "fourth " << a << std::endl;

MyIncrementFifth(ptr);
a = *ptr;
delete ptr;
std::cout << "fifth " << a << std::endl;
```